# How can I get the same result as CoreNlp.run?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I use CoreNlp to get the parse tree ,and the maven dependency is like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
<version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
```

The result is different from CoreNlp.run(process the same sentence),and I want to get the same result like CoreNlp.run, what should i do?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Likely, this is from using a different parser model locally. corenlp.run uses the shift-reduce constituency parser for efficiency, whereas the default parser in the CoreNLP distribution is a PCFG. The tradeoff here is between a faster and more accurate model (shift reduce) versus faster loading time and smaller model disk size (the PCFG). For more details: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml (note that you'll need to include an additional model jar)